# Why must we always use different variables with overlapping quantifiers?

Tags: predicate-logic

The statement "If anything is good and all good things are safe, then it is safe" is expressed logically as:

(x){[Gx • (y)(Gy ⊃ Sy)] ⊃ Sx}

What are the ambiguities or wrong interpretations that might result if I used the same variable 'x' throughout the logical expression? Or why is it wrong to use the same variable 'x' throughout?

(x){[Gx • (x)(Gx ⊃ Sx)] ⊃ Sx}

Notice that the "it" at the end of "If anything is good and all good things are safe, then it is safe" refers to one of the good things mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: For example, ∀x∀y(P(x) ∨ Q(y)) ≠ ∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x)), because on the right you only need each object to be P or to be Q, whereas on the left you need all objects to be P or all objects to be Q,  see [Distribution of Quantifiers
over Conjunction and Disjunction](https://cse.buffalo.edu/~rapaport/191/distqfroverandor.html).

Comment: Per FOL's (nested) scoping rule, the occurrence of 'x' in your (Gx ⊃ Sx) is ambiguous to refer to the outer or the inner bound variable x?...

Comment: In a simple example like this, potentially you could use the same variable x and employ a scoping rule that says when a variable is present within the scope of two quantifiers, use the most closely nested one. But it would still look awkward and be more difficult for a human to understand. It's better just to use different variables.

Comment: @Conifold Why does the expression ∀x∀y(P(x) ∨ Q(y)) imply that all objects has to be P or all objects has to be Q? I think the expression can imply the possibility for having objects  belonging to both P and Q. Does not it say that for any pair of objects you choose, either the object will be a P or it will be a Q or it can be both P and Q?

Comment: Logical ∨ is inclusive or, so all objects having to be P or all objects having to be Q includes possibilities that some are both or even that all are both. But, in any case, all must be the same type, whether P or Q.

Answer (score 0):

Because the same variable 'x' throughout the logical expression can lead to ambiguities or wrong interpretations because it can make it unclear which quantifier is binding which variable!

In the first expression, (x){[Gx • (y)(Gy ⊃ Sy)] ⊃ Sx}, the quantifier '(x)' binds the variable 'x' in the antecedent of the implication, while the quantifier '(y)' binds the variable 'y' in the consequent of the implication. This makes it clear that the "it" at the end of "If anything is good and all good things are safe, then it is safe" refers to one of the good things mentioned at the beginning.

In the second expression, (x){[Gx • (x)(Gx ⊃ Sx)] ⊃ Sx}, the quantifier '(x)' binds both occurrences of the variable 'x' in the expression. This means that the "it" at the end of "If anything is good and all good things are safe, then it is safe" could refer to any object in the universe of discourse, not just to a good thing.

That's the problem here